# python inheritance: __init__ (self, self)?

Tags: python

I see a piece of code that is

```
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
```

I'm confused what the `self, self` does. I'm used to something like this.

```
class TestClient(EClient):
    def __init__(self, wrapper):
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper)
```

Can someone explain `self, self`?

Comment: It's initialising the current object `self` using a superclass's init method `EClient.__init__`, passing an additional argument, `self`. To find out what that will do, see `EClient.__init__`.

Comment: I'm guessing from the context you provided that EClient constructor takes an argument of type EWrapper. `EClient.__init__(self, self)` calls the EClient constructor with self as the wrapper parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self is an object of the class "IBapi" and also an instance of the classes "EWrapper" and "EClient" through inheritance. I am guessing that the constructor of "EClient" gets an instance of "EWrapper" as a parameter. You can think of your code like this:

```py
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
  def __init__(self):
    wrapper = self
    EClient.__init__(self, wrapper)
```

Comment: Why do we need to pass self as a first parameter in EClient.__init__(self, wrapper), shouldn't we just pass wrapper?